# Login Redirect ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication

I'm in need of some help in redirecting the standard Login tool in Visual Studio.

My project is using the web ASP.configuration tool & I'm using the standard tools provided in Visual Studio 2010.

I have roles setup each have their own folder in the project which need redirecting based on their login.

For example, when an admin logs in, they should be redirected to `~/Admin/default.aspx`
I have tried some code on the button but cant seem to get it to work.

This is my code below:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Admin"))
            {
               Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Default.aspx");
            }
            else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "User"))
            {
               Response.Redirect("~/User/Default.aspx");
            }               
        }
    }
```

Any help?

J

Comment: You need to set the `AuthenticateEventArgs` parameter Authenticated to true to tell the system that the user is authenticated.  However, you need the current request to continue so that the proper authentication cookie gets set, so you want to call `Response.Redirect(..., false)`

Comment: Have no idea how to do what you have asked?

Comment: How can you not know how to do what I said?  If you don't, you are in WAY over your head, and probably should be reading a book or taking a course.  This is as basic as it gets, setting a Boolean value on a parameter object and adding a false to a method call.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I guess I will read a book or take a course (this is a hobby & I don't pretend to be a pro)

Comment: What exactly do you find so difficult to understand about adding  ", false" to your Response.Redirect? or typing "e.Authenticated = true;"?  THis is not "pro" stuff, it's so basic that "Hello World" is more complicated.

Comment: Sorry, but if someone just starts using asp.net e.g. last week & starts using it without no prior knowledge. I would further like to add that learning capabilities is down to the be holder not the teacher therefore its not advisable to judge someone on one request after all its a forum which is the whole point. As I said thank you for your feedback I will take it on broad. Oh and thank you for turning something fun into something not so fun because I didn't know what I was doing.

Comment: It's your responsibility to put in some effort to understand things.  I gave you the exact answer to your question without any judgement.  When you came back, unwilling to put in any effort to understand what I said, that's when I was flabbergasted by your inability to understand even the most simple of concepts.  Because of that, I suggested that you're in over your head.. even the most basic of C# concepts are not understandable by you, so you need to start at a lower level and read a book or take a course.  If you can't understand the simple concepts I mention, you are lost already.

Comment: You're asking how to walk when you don't even know what legs are, much less how to crawl or stand.  The issue here is that you don't understand the ASP.NET request pipeline, or even that it exists.  Without that knowledge, you don't understand why you need to finish your request in order for authentication to work.  These are not "Hello World, I'm just starting" concepts.  You have a lot to learn.

Comment: As I said, thank you for your feedback, someone else has been very kind enough to guide me through your answer not given me the answer but guide me through where it needs to go & the purpose. Thank you again for your answer it was a great help.